# ‘Install now’ reverts backwards

Tags: system-installation

I’m trying to install Ubuntu (latest stable) on a Lenovo Legion Y520.

I get to the installation type page, choose ‘erase disk and install ubuntu.’ I have a 500GB SSD and 1TB HDD. I select the larger drive and press install now...

... then I get brought back to the installation type page. It becomes an endless cycle back and forth when I keep trying to install. I have used two different USBs to make sure it wasn’t a corrupted bootable medium.

I have made sure to disable Intel RAID. I am using UEFI to boot.

When trying to use manual partitioning it also complains things are in use by the RHEL volume group (I had RH on before.)

Comment: Please specify which version of Ubuntu you are installing

Comment: @Rooney Latest stable release.